# If Statement, having a condition meet on specific numbers while variable increments

Tags: swift, if-statement

Simple problems which I just can't seem to figure out in my small head. I have a variable which will be updated and increment sequentially i.e 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.. and so on just to be clear. I am trying to implement a condition for when the numbers are 1 and 2 beep and for 3 and 4 do this, this should alternate. let me show you using code.

```
func doSomething(number : Int) {
    //number is increment sequentially: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4...
    let number : Int = number
    if number is 1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10... {
        //play a sound
    } else if number is 3, 4, 7, 8, 11, 12... {
        //vibrate
    }
}
```

My concern isn't what happens inside the if statements but the logic in the condition of the if statement.

Comment: Unrelated but get rid of the line `let number : Int = number`. It's pointless to define a local constant that hides the parameter of the same name.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a total alternative: *don't* increment a number. The numbers are not needed; they are a red herring. What you want is to perform a certain "next" action each time we need a new action. So let's write a *state machine* where each successive change of state behaves as you describe.

```
struct StateMachine {
    enum TickTock {
        case tick
        case tock
    }
    private var tickTock = TickTock.tock
    private var alternator = false
    mutating func nextState() {
        self.alternator = !self.alternator
        if self.alternator {
            self.tickTock = self.tickTock == .tick ? .tock : .tick
        }
        print(self.tickTock)
    }
}
```

So the only thing you have to do is keep a StateMachine instance on hand and call its `nextState` every time you need to perform a new action.
Here's a test and its output (don't be misled by the loop; there are no actual numbers in this story, it's just a test bed):

```
var machine = StateMachine()
for _ in 0..<20 {
    machine.nextState()
}
/*
tick
tick
tock
tock
tick
tick
tock
tock
tick
tick
tock
tock
tick
tick
tock
tock
tick
tick
tock
tock
*/
```

If every time we print "tick" you make a sound, and every time we print "tock" you vibrate, you'll be doing exactly what your spec requires.

Comment: `self.alternator.toggle()`

Comment: If he’s using a high enough version of Swift. But why limit the usefulness of the code?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (number % 4) == 1 || (number % 4) == 2 {
    ding()
} else {
    wiggle()
}
```

Comment: While my answer could be considered more "clever", this is more readable.

Comment: Nitpicking: Parentheses aren't needed

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((number + 1) / 2) % 2 == 1 {
    // play a sound
} else {
    // vibrate
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to @rmaddy's answer but it uses one fewer operation:

```
if (number + 1) & 2 == 2 {
    // play a sound
} else {
    // vibrate
}
```

**How does this work?**

This works by observing that when counting in binary:

```
1   001
2   010
3   011
4   100
5   101
6   110
7   111
```

the two's digit (second digit from the right) changes in the following pattern: `0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...`.  By adding one, we shift the pattern to `1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...`.  So, then to check the 2's digit do a *bitwise AND* (`&`) with `2` and check if that is `2`.

I would do it this way if I were programming it in assembly, but for Swift I like @matt's solution.